# Returning a pointer from a template function with iterators parameters

Tags: c++, templates, pointers, iterator, dynamic-allocation

Lately I have been learning dynamic memory allocation.

For practice purposes I tried to make a universal function that can accept iterators as parameters and then copies from beginning to end to a dynamically allocated array, then returns a pointer.

I want to make the function using complete deduction, without specifying return type when calling the function for example.

I would also like functions declaration to be as simple as possible, without any libraries (except `std::remove_reference` from `type_traits` if needed), IF possible.

The following code won't compile. And I know the code is useless from a logical view. I just wanted to show you my intentions and what I wanted to achieve...

```
#include <iostream>
#include <vector>
#include <type_traits>

template<typename T>
auto* returnPointer(T iter1, T iter2) -> std::remove_reference<decltype(*iter1)>::type
{
    auto p = new std::remove_reference<decltype(*iter1)>::type [10];
    auto p_help = p;

    while(iter1 != iter2)
    {
        *p_help = *iter1;
        p_help++;
        iter1++;
    }

    return p;
}

int main ()
{
    std::vector<int> v {0,1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9};
    int *p = returnPointer(v.begin(), v.end());

    for(int i = 0; i < 10; i++)
        std::cout << p[i] << " ";

    return 0;
}
```

I understand why it wont compile, what I cannot figure out how to make it work the way I imagined it...

Any help is very appreciated! :)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

1. When using trailing return type declaration you should use `auto` directly;
2. you need to add `typename` for `std::remove_reference<...>::type`, or use `std::remove_reference_t` (since C++14) instead;

Then

```
auto  returnPointer(T iter1, T iter2) -> typename std::remove_reference<decltype(*iter1)>::type*
//  ~                                    ~~~~~~~~                                              ~
```

[LIVE](http://rextester.com/OMYRX42061)

---

Other suggestions:

1. Since C++14 you can take advantage of return type deduction. so just

   ```
   template<typename T>
   auto returnPointer(T iter1, T iter2)
   {
       auto p = new std::remove_reference_t<decltype(*iter1)> [10];
       ...
       return p;  // return type will be deduced from p
   }
   ```
2. You can use `std::distance` to get the number of the elements, like

   ```
   auto p = new std::remove_reference_t<decltype(*iter1)> [std::distance(iter1, iter2)];
   ```
3. Don't forget to `delete[]` the pointer at last, i.e.

   ```
   delete[] p;
   ```

[LIVE](http://rextester.com/UXVZ65452)

Comment: I was close! Amazing! I forgot `typename` in one more place, the place where I was allocating an array. I just tested and it works! Thanks! Can you please explain what is the secret behind `*` after `type` ?

Comment: @galaxyworks It's simple, `std::remove_reference<...>::type` will return the type of element, adding `*` makes it a type of the pointer to the element. For you code works with `std::vector<int>`, `std::remove_reference<...>::type` will be `int`, adding `*` makes it `int*`.

Comment: I understand now! Thanks for the answer and detailed explanation!